# Merge cells based on week number openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am generating an excel sheet based on date range.
Along with date I am also finding week number.

Currently I am able to generate excel sheet like this below:

| Date | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 1/4/2021 | 1 |
| 1/5/2021 | 1 |
| 1/6/2021 | 1 |
| 1/7/2021 | 1 |
| 1/8/2021 | 1 |
| 1/9/2021 | 1 |
| 1/10/2021 | 1 |
| 1/11/2021 | 2 |
| 1/12/2021 | 2 |
| 1/13/2021 | 2 |
| 1/14/2021 | 2 |
| 1/15/2021 | 2 |
| 1/16/2021 | 2 |
| 1/17/2021 | 2 |
| 1/18/2021 | 3 |
| 1/19/2021 | 3 |
| 1/20/2021 | 3 |
| 1/21/2021 | 3 |
| 1/22/2021 | 3 |
| 1/23/2021 | 3 |
| 1/24/2021 | 3 |

I am expecting it like this:

| Date | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 1/4/2021 | 1 |
| 1/5/2021 |  |
| 1/6/2021 |  |
| 1/7/2021 |  |
| 1/8/2021 |  |
| 1/9/2021 |  |
| 1/10/2021 |  |
| 1/11/2021 | 2 |
| 1/12/2021 |  |
| 1/13/2021 |  |
| 1/14/2021 |  |
| 1/15/2021 |  |
| 1/16/2021 |  |
| 1/17/2021 |  |
| 1/18/2021 | 3 |
| 1/19/2021 |  |
| 1/20/2021 |  |
| 1/21/2021 |  |
| 1/22/2021 |  |
| 1/23/2021 |  |
| 1/24/2021 |  |

Used markdown tables here, But column showing week, those cells should be merged based on same week number.

code used:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime.strptime("2021-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date =  datetime.strptime("2022-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
delta = timedelta(days=1)

wb = Workbook()
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("Test sheet")
row_number = 4

while start_date <= end_date:
    ws2[f'A{row_number}'] = f"{start_date.month}/{start_date.day}/{start_date.year}"
    ws2[f'B{row_number}'] = start_date.isocalendar()[1]
    ws2[f'C{row_number}'] = start_date.strftime("%B")
    row_number+=1
    start_date += delta
```

Comment: You can use `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 1):

You can change:

```
ws2[f'B{row_number}'] = start_date.isocalendar()[1]
```

to:

```
ws2[f'B{row_number}'] = start_date.isocalendar()[1] if start_date.weekday() == 0 else ''
```